# Is Microsoft Access An Appropriate SO topic

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is SO an appropriate form to discuss the front end of Microsoft Access, specifically, Macros SQL, forms and VBA code? I know to keep Access DBA questions on Database Administrators, without any front-end design questions.

Comment: Sounds okay, depending on the exact question.

Comment: I would say it depends on the specifics of the question.  Certain questions on the topic would be fine, others may be better on Super User.

Comment: Are you coding? Then yes. Microsoft Access SQL, Macros and VBA code are all coding topics. Are you backing up the database? Then that's more of a SuperUser question.

Comment: If you call debugging macros coding @MartijnPieters then I'm coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, given that the [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag exists with about 15k questions and a proper tag wiki. I'd say it's on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *Some* questions about access are on topic, but that's not to say that *all* questions surrounding access would be on topic.